# Reading wikitables with unequal cell sizes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, wikipedia

I am trying to read wikitables from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products

I am using the following:

```
    import pandas as pd
    page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products'    
    wikitables = pd.read_html(page, attrs={"class":"wikitable"})
    table1 = wikitables[0]
```

Since the cell sizes are not equal (e.g. the year '1979' spans multiple models of Apple), this skews some cells to fill up the 'blank' cell and introduces NaNs in the wrong cells (e.g. values from the column 'model' end up in the column 'year').

[here is a screenshot of the dataframe with skewed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifzFz.png)

Is there a way of fixing this while reading the html? Or another way of consistently filling those empty spaces in the cell so the values don't get skewed?

Thanks in advance!